# Import existing Google App Engine module into Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, android-studio

I created and deployed months ago a Google App Engine project in Eclipse with the Google Cloud plugin. Now I'm interested in continue the development of this project in Android Studio to avoid using two different IDEs and to have it integrated with my Android application.
I've found that Android Studio has a wizard to create a new Google Cloud module but I have not found any clue on how to import an existing one. Does anyone know a proper way of doing it avoiding the task of create a new one and paste all the code from eclipse?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Gradle with the gradle-appengine-plugin you should be able to simply copy the appengine module directory into your android studio project and include it in your settings.gradle.  A sync will cause the IDE to detect the module and you can create a new App Engine run configuration and select that module to run the dev server.

If you're using Maven then you'll need to port your build over to Gradle to get it to work with Android Studio.